# Как растянуть флекс элемент на 2 строки?

Tags: reactjs, swiper

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Всем привет, юзаю react swiper, как сделать что бы датчик температуры занимал 2 строки а не увеличивал строку?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
должно быть примерно как на гридах когда конкретному элементу задаешь grid-row 1/2, но как сделать это на флексах?

```js
      <Swiper
                    spaceBetween={24}   
                    slidesPerView={'auto'}
                    grid={{
                        fill: 'row',
                        rows: 2,
                    }}
                >
                    {roomDevices.map(device =>
                        <SwiperSlide
                            style={{
                                height: device.code === 'temp_hum_sensor'? 300: 136,
                                width: 288
                            }}
                            key={device.id}>
                            <DeviceView
                                key={device.id}
                                device={device}
                            />
                        </SwiperSlide>
                    )}
                </Swiper>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понимаю вопрос, вам нужно элементу у которого стоит `display: flex` добавить свойство `flex-wrap: wrap;`

```
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap

Comment: У самого контейнера стоит flex-wrap: wrap, элементы переходят на новую строку как надо, ну мне надо что бы один элемент был в 2 раза выше других и при этом занимал 2 строки а не увеличивал размер строки. А получается что если одному элементу задать высоту 300px то вся строка где находится этот элемент становится 300px

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно поменять структуру в html, и выделить под большой элемент отдельный блок.
https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-fire-8omygk?file=/src/App.js:87-96

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]